# WPF 4 blurry font

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I recently upgraded my WPF project from .NET v3.5 to v4.0 and I'm still running into issues where all of my text is blurry. I have the following set in my main window.

```
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
```

From what I've read this issue was fixed in WPF 4.

Here is what it looks like using the following markup.

[image: WPF v4.0 blurry font]

```
<TextBlock Text="Sample with TextOptions..." 
           FontFamily="Arial, sans-serif" 
           FontSize="14"
           TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
           TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" />
<TextBlock Text="Sample without TextOptions..." 
           FontFamily="Arial, sans-serif" 
           FontSize="14" />
```

While I can definetly see a difference in text, it still isn't as clear as I would expect it to be. Am I just crazy!?

Comment: Care to post a small screenshot of how the text is displayed?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. The screenshot is zoomed in. Of course there will be blurring when zooming a bitmap. That's got NOTHING to do with WPF. Post a non-zoomed screenshot of your WPF Window exhibiting the supposed blur.

Comment: Looks completely normal to me.  The w, t and h in "with" are rendered exactly the same as the same letters in "what" in the text above it.  The "without" version certainly has iffy anti-aliasing but that's a known limitation of ideal mode.  Could be a problem with [dpi awareness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308410.aspx) but the text isn't tall enough.  Type the same text in Notepad, put the windows next to each other, zoom in and compare pixels.